# How to resolve Cannot connect to RSSD server while configuring Replication server in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sybase-rs

```
I. 2021/03/02 20:28:09. RSSD server is 'ASE1'.
I. 2021/03/02 20:28:09. Reading 'ASE1.RS1_RSSD..rs_config' for system configuration parameters.
E. 2021/03/02 20:28:09. ERROR #31083 GLOBAL RS(GLOBAL RS) - eneric/cfg/cfginit.c(3492)
Cannot connect to RSSD server. ct_connect failed.
E. 2021/03/02 20:28:09. ERROR #1027 GLOBAL RS(GLOBAL RS) - eneric/cfg/cfginit.c(3492)
Open Client Client-Library error: Error: 84083972, Severity 5 -- 'ct_connect(): network packet layer: internal net library error: Net-Lib protocol driver call to connect two endpoints failed', Operating System error 111 -- 'Socket connect failed - errno 111 Connection refused'.
F. 2021/03/02 20:28:09. FATAL ERROR #18028 GLOBAL RS(GLOBAL RS) - /servmain/servmain.c(345)
Initialization failed. Server is shutting down.
```

The above error occured while i ran RUN_RS1 as part of my work.

```
[root@node1]# cat RUN_RS1
#
# Runserver file for Replication Server 'RS1'. Created by rs_init.   
#
/opt/sybase_rs/REP-16_0/bin/repserver -SRS1 -C/sybase_rs/RS.cfg \
-E/opt/sybase_rs/RS.log -I/opt/sybase_rs/interfaces 
 1>>/sybase_rs/RS1.stdout \
 2>>/sybase_rs/RS1.stderr \
```

rs_init was completed prior to this and this was successfull also. While
running ASE1 resource file was used(It is too huge to mention here). To
check the database i used isql to login, But i failed there too.

```
[root@node1 bin]# ./isql -Usa -S10.167.2.11:4904


The context allocation routine failed when it tried to load localization f 
files!!
One or more following problems may caused the failure

Cannot access the sybase home directory, please check environment 
variable SYBASE or ~sybase
An error occurred when attempting to allocate localization-related 
structures.
```

The above command did not succeed even after sourcing environment related
to sybase. SYBASE.env. Even ASE is not running due to this error.

```
[root@node1 sybase_rs]# source SYBASE.env
[root@node1 sybase_rs]# ./SYBASE.sh
[root@node1 sybase_rs]# echo $SYBASE
/opt/sybase_rs
[root@node1 sybase_rs]# cd OCS-16_0/bin
[root@node1 bin]# pwd
 /opt/sybase_rs/OCS-16_0/bin
[root@node1 bin]# ./isql -v
SAP CTISQL Utility/16.0 SP03 PL08/P-EBF29213/DRV.16.0.03.08/Linux 
 x86_64/Linux 2.6.18-128.el5 x86_64/BUILD1600-025/64bit/OPT/Fri Jan 10 
01:27:42 2020

Confidential property of SAP AG or an SAP affiliate company.
Copyright 2020
SAP AG or an SAP affiliate company.  All rights reserved.
Unpublished rights reserved under U.S. copyright laws.

 This software contains confidential and trade secret information of SAP AG 
 or
 an SAP affiliate company.  Use,  duplication or disclosure of the software 
 and
 documentation by the  U.S.  Government is subject to restrictions set forth
 in a license agreement between the Government and SAP AG or an SAP affiliate
 company,  or other written agreement specifying the Government's rights to
 use the software and any applicable FAR provisions, for example, FAR 52.227- 
 19.
 SAP AG or an SAP affiliate company
```

Comment: First thing i have checked is passwords file, it is proper as i have given the right password for ASE server while configuring.

Comment: cat interfaces 
 
ASE1 
        master tcp ether 10.167.2.11 5000
        query tcp ether 10.167.2.11 5000


ASE1_BS
        master tcp ether 10.167.2.11 5001
        query tcp ether 10.167.2.11 5001

RS1
        master tcp ether 10.167.2.11 4904
        query tcp ether 10.167.2.11 4904

Comment: Please update the question with details on what you were doing when the error was generated; were you running `rs_init` to create the repserver? were you starting up the repserver? was the repserver already up and running and if so what command had you issued that generated this error?  if running `rs_init` were you using a resource file? is `ASE1` up and running? does the `ASE1.RS1_RSSD` database exist? can you log into `ASE1` and successfully `use RS1_RSSD`?

Comment: @markp-fuso, updated the question with the details.

Comment: what directory are you sitting in when you run `./isql`?  what is the value of `$SYBASE`? what's the output from `./isql -v`?

Comment: Updated the details in the question @markp-fuso

Comment: the `isql` error indicates the `isql` binary was found but some environment variables were not configured properly - hard to tell the issue here without going into more details on the contents of the `SYBASE.env` (not really needed) and `SYBASE.sh` scripts and comparing the contents with the actual Sybase software installation directory(s) on the local host; `isql -v` looks good; the comment about `ASE not running due to this [isql] error` is confusing, ie, I can't tell if **a)** your ASE instance is down or **b)** you're unable to `isql` into the ASE instance ...

Comment: have you verified the ASE instance is up (eg, check the ASE errorlog, check for a corresponding `dataserver` process running on the host)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229569/discussion-between-pooja-g-and-markp-fuso).

Comment: Issue was resolved after reinstallation of ASE and RS, Not sure what was the problem. Hence closing this. Thanks markp-fuso for looking into this.